# Access Tools in Save Menu with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, ms-office

I use C# to turn ppt files into jpg images but I also want the program to resave the same ppt with compressed pictures and cropped pictures, I want to use settings in Tools menu when saving a file. How can I access them with Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint?

Sorry, I should clarify. I want to re-save the same ppt but with those settings of compression and cropping. Basically, I want to resave the ppt file and then break it into images. I need a ppt with compressed images in order to save space on the pc.

Right now I use this to save JPGs.

```
  file.SaveCopyAs(outputPath + "CONVERTED.jpg", PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

[image]

Comment: Those settings control how PowerPoint compresses inserted images in the PPTX file. They have nothing to do with what happens when you save as images. Try using the Presentation object's .Export method, which lets you specify the directory to export images to, the format to export to (e.g. "PNG") and the horizontal and vertical resolution in pixels. Supply just the horizontal resolution and it will provide the proportional vertical resolution.  The images will be exported as Slide1.PNG, Slide2.PNG etc.  OR use the Slide.Export method on each slide, which lets you set the exported file's name

Comment: added clarifications. I need to resave ppt file itself. Saving it into jpgs is already handled.

Comment: I'm not sure if whether this is possible or not, but wanted to mention that if the file's been saved once with a fairly high level of image compression, saving it again with lower compression will not bring data back.  I'd imagine that you're going the opposite direction, re-saving the file at a higher compression level, so that wouldn't be an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer for you:

In the PPTX file's PPT folder, you'll find a presProps.xml file.
In it, you'll find something like this:

```
<p:extLst>
    <p:ext uri="{E76CE94A-603C-4142-B9EB-6D1370010A27}">
        <p14:discardImageEditData xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="0"/>
    </p:ext>
    <p:ext uri="{D31A062A-798A-4329-ABDD-BBA856620510}">
        <p14:defaultImageDpi xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="96"/>
    </p:ext>
    <p:ext uri="{FD5EFAAD-0ECE-453E-9831-46B23BE46B34}">
        <p15:chartTrackingRefBased xmlns:p15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2012/main" val="1"/>
    </p:ext>
</p:extLst>
```

From this, it appears that you could save a copy of the PPTX, change defaultImageDPI and possibly discardImageEditData in the XML, re-open and resave the PPTX from PPT.

It doesn't seem to allow values below 96dpi; set it lower and it reverts to 96 when you open the file in PPT.